# How to search in a Arraylist

Tags: c#-4.0

I created an arraylist of `Student` type. `Student` has name, subject information in it. Suppose my `ArrayList` has values like (sam, maths), (john, english), (mat, science). If i want to find out which student has science stream, then how to search it in an `ArrayList`.

I think it may be done by using binarysearch or indexof methods, but not getting it right.

Comment: specifically `ArrayList` is an array of?

Comment: Given that you're using C# 4, why are you using ArrayList instead of a generic collection?

Comment: type student class. and this class has a constructor to set the values for name and subject. so you can say we have to give namea and subject as parameter while adding.like, list.Add(new student(john, maths)), where list is the name of the arraylist

Comment: You can simplify your code using LINQ, it will remove the 'i' declaration and the foreach loop, just use : `var results = albums.FindAll(a => a.artist == txt || a.tag == txt);` if you want only the first or last result just replace 'FindAll' with the 'First' or 'Last' method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how I did in the end. Sorry I forgot to answer this one.

```
  public int search(object sender, List<albums> al)
    {
        int i = -1;
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        foreach (albums dc in al)
        {
            if ((dc.artist == txt) ||(dc.tag == txt))
            {
                i = (al.IndexOf(dc));
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you created an arraylist of Student type ?

I'm pretty sure that you should go with a generic type-safe list : `List<T>`

To do your searches you could use LINQ :

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(new Student { Lastname = "Smith" });
students.Add(new Student { Lastname = "Foo" });
students.Add(new Student { Lastname = "SmithFoo" });
students.Add(new Student { Lastname = "SmithBar" });

var searchResults = from student in students
     where student.Lastname.StartsWith("Smith")
     select student;
```

This code will search in your students list and return three students : Smith, SmithFoo and SmithBar

Comment: Thanks mmorel, i shifted to list generics and it worked perfect. you can have a look at my edited code to see how i searched. welcome for suggestions.